# Solving for edge cases on "Add mins to 24 hour clock" - certain edge cases failing

Tags: python, python-3.x, time

I'm trying to solve this challenge:
https://profound.academy/python-introduction/jAdU8ObJbCCYPG45hJWz

I have solved it for all inputs listed, from the public info on the course (hours, minutes, added minutes):

- 14, 28, 75 = 15:43
- 14, 28, 1440 = 14:28
- 7, 50, 5320 = 0:30
- 23, 58, 2 = 0:0
- (In comments): 18, 12, 1139 = 13:11

However, one or more of the unlisted (private) edge cases is still failing. Here is my Python code:

```
# Take input, truncating to unit
hours = int(input()) % 24
mins = int(input()) % 60 
addMins = int(input()) % 1440 

# Add mins clock has been stuck
newMins = (mins + addMins) % 60
newHours =  hours + (addMins // 60)
newHours = newHours % 23

print(newHours, ':', newMins, sep='')
```

Comment: In your own words, where the code says `newHours = newHours % 23`, what do you expect this to mean? (Hint: how many hours are there in a day? Why does the code **not** say `newMins = (mins + addMins) % 59`?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your calculation of `newHours` is wrong (you have the right idea, but there's a bug there) - there are 24 hours a day, so you should take modulo 24, not 23:

```py
newHours = newHours % 24
```

**EDIT:**
There's another bug I missed there. It misses the fact that when the new minutes overflow over 60 they should add an hour. Let's clarify this with a simple example - assume the clock shows 00:45, and you move it forward 20 minutes. 45+20=65, so you'd want the minutes to display 65 % 60 = 5, but you've also moved an hour forward - it's not 00:05, but 01:05.

To express this in Python:

```py
newMins = mins + addMins
newHours =  hours + (newMins // 60)
newHours = newHours % 24
newMins = newMins % 60
print(newHours, ':', newMins, sep='')
```

Answer (score 0):

i think the problem is here

```
newHours =  hours + (addMins // 60)
newHours = newHours % 23
```

consider that hours is 23 and addMins 60+ newHours is now 24
so if you make `newHours = newHours % 23` you get 1 : minutes , wich is not the desired answer , it should be `newHours = newHours % 24`